# Object Oriented Programming - Iterating Through Arguments

Tags: python

I am having issues looping through an argument and just displaying the "cat" argument. Keep in mind i am adding items to an empty list self.item. I am also using the function showAllFormatted to format the data.

I tried looping and then using "return AllItems.ShowAllFormatted(i.cat)" but no results showed after adding items to my empty list.

```
class AllItems:

    def __init__(self, cat,comment, worth, amount):
        self.cat = cat
        self.comment= comment
        self.worth = worth
        self.amount = amount

    def ShowAllFormatted(self):
        print('{:>10}:>10}{:>10}{:>10}'.format(self.cat, 
        self.comment,self.worth,self.amount))

class Collection:

    def __init__(self):
        self.an_item = []

    def add_item(self):
        item = AllItems(cat, comment, worth,amount)
        self.item.append(item)

    def ShowAllItems(self):
        for i in self.an_item:
             AllItems.ShowAllFormatted(i)
        return i

    def showAllCat(self):
        for item in self.an_item:
             return item.cat
```

Comment: You have `self.cat`, then ask for `self.category`.

Comment: @kwinkunks I have fixed it and changed it to self.cat.

Comment: @ajburnett344 I am noticing several other problems in your code. I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version of your code that works... it might even do what you want:

```
class Item:

    def __init__(self, cat, comment, worth, amount):
        self.cat = cat
        self.comment= comment
        self.worth = worth
        self.amount = amount

    def show_formatted(self):
        print('{:>10}{:>10}{:>10}{:>10}'.format(self.cat, 
                                                self.comment,
                                                self.worth,
                                                self.amount,
                                                )
             )
        return None


class Collection:

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def add_item(self, cat, comment, worth, amount):
        item = Item(cat, comment, worth, amount)
        self.items.append(item)
        return None

    def show_all_items(self):
        for item in self.items:
            item.show_formatted()
        return None

    def get_all_cats(self):
        return [item.cat for item in self.items]
```

You can test it with:

```
>>> c = Collection()  # Instantiate a Collection object.
>>> c.add_item('C', 'comment', 10, 1000)  # Add an item to it.
>>> c.add_item('C', 'words', 9, 999)  # Add another.
>>> c.show_all_items()
         C   comment        10      1000
         C     words         9       999
```

There are quite a few things going on here:

- I changed the name of the `AllItems` class to `Item`, because it seemed like it wanted to represent a single thing (from the `__ini__()` you wrote).
- I changed the name of the `ShowAllFormatted` method, because each instance of the class (`self`, basically) only has to worry about one thing: itself. IT doesn't know / care about being part of a collection.
- The `add_item` method in the `Collection` class didn't accept any arguments so I added them. Now it can instantiate instances of the `Item` class with some data.
- I got rid of `ShowAllCat` because I wasn't sure what it should do. Maybe take a cat name as an argument, then loop over items with that cat, and call their `show_formatted` method? Something like that. But you won't need to pass anything to `show_formatted`, it doesn't take any other arguments right now (but it could, say to control how the things are printed).

I fixed a couple of other things, and used more Pythonic names (uppercase initial for classes, lowercase for everything else). But most of the rest of it is unchanged.

Don't forget to add docstrings to all your classes and methods!

Comment: Thank you! I will test the code now. I did need the showallcat because i wanted to show all categories from the added item.

Comment: I tried to loop the cat using return item.cat but it only brings up one cat instead of all of them.

Comment: You can only return once from any function or method. So you will have to collect the cats in some sort of collection and return that, or print them in a loop, or something like that. I added an example of the former approach to my answer. I called it `get_all_cats` because 'show' implies printing somehow.

Comment: wow your great that works! last question, is there any way to get unique values when looping through cats?

Comment: @ajburnett344 Definitely! You can do anything with Python :) Here are 2 ways: make an empty list, loop over the items, but only append to the list if they are not already in the list (`if item not in unique_items: unique_items.append(item)` sort of thing), or do `list(set(list_of_cats))`, because a Python `set` can only contain unique items.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant `self.category = cat` in your constructor.